# java : invalid key size while using aes encryption after using JCE security policy version 8

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm trying to generate AES key of size 256 bit and I downloaded the JCE security policy of version 8 and I placed the US_export_policy.jar and the local_policy.jar in the jre/lib/security folder. Is there anything I've left out in the code and what could be the cause for the exception?

This is what I've coded and it gives me an illegal key size exception.

Here's the code :

```
            kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            kgen.init(256);
            SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            SecureRandom srandom = new SecureRandom();
            srandom.nextBytes(iv);
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            System.out.println(iv);
```

Here, iv is the initialization vector that I'm using further in the code.

Would greatly appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

This is exception I'm getting :

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1039)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:805)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1396)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
    at com.global.DocMananger.Crypto.main(Crypto.java:145)
```

This is the line that's throwing the error :

```
Cipher cipherAES = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipherAES.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey, ivspec);
```

Comment: First off, the IV size should be 16 bytes (128 bits), not 32 bytes. Secondly, if I correct that mistake and properly install the unlimited crypto policy files I don't get any error.

Comment: I changed the IV to  16 bytes, still is the same exception. I have copied the JCE jars to jre/lib/security, is there anything more to be done?

Comment: Java 8 which version you are using? I am not sure in which of these two version it works, check jdk1.8.0_91 and jdk1.8.0_144.

Comment: it's jdk1.8.0_141, the same exception is being generated...

Comment: Then check with jdk1.8.0_91. Surely it will work.

Comment: After all, shouldn't it work with all versions?

Comment: When i working on AES encryption 6 months before, it didn't work with all version of Java 8 even changed JCE policy files.

Comment: You can raise question in Java8 forum regarding this. Before that ensure from you side.

Comment: sure, thanks, Is there any other alternative other than JCE to generate 256 bit aes leys?

Comment: Shall i know whether it works with jdk1.8.0_91? No alternative solution as i know. You can use 128 bit key to not change JCE.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work, but when I deploy my application to the server, I don't want to configure the java settings there. So I don't feel using JCE is good alternative

Comment: For 32 bytes key size only it requires to change JCE file, if you use 16 bytes key size then no need to replace JCE files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jdk1.8.0_91` package, it will work after changing JCE policy files.

In `jdk1.8.0_144`, it won't work even changing JCE files. Seems it has some issues in that version. Ask you query in Java8 forum regarding this.